# Run cloned android camera app

Tags: android, eclipse, camera

I have cloned the Android Camera app from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git

But I was hoping to build and run this in Android Studio or Eclipse. I've noticed there is no AndroidManifest.xml file.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Is it even possible?

Comment: The "apps" in the Android Open Source Project (AOSP) are meant to be built as part of a full firmware build. Even if there was a manifest file, there a very good chance that the Camera app would depend upon things that are outside of the Android SDK.

Comment: Found a solution. It was Camera2 I should have cloned, not Camera. Camera2 includes the Manifest file. After importing into eclipse and making some changes I have got it running.

Comment: How did you do it, what did you change? Can you link missing files if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. It was Camera2 I should have cloned, not Camera. Camera2 includes the Manifest file. After importing into eclipse and making some changes I have got it running.

Link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2

Comment: Can you please share your method? It will make your question more meaningful.